# Is there a way to retain the rownames after row deletion

Tags: r

When i try deleting a row below, the rownames also gets deleted. Is there a way to retain the rownames?

```
df <-data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(5,6,7))
df <- df[!df['a'] == 2,]
df
  a b
1 1 5
3 3 7
```

Expected output

```
df
  a b
1 1 5
2 3 7
```

Basically there should be a continuous row names :)

Comment: What do you mean by "retain" row names? In the example the last row has name 3 and it still has name 3 after you delete the row. Do you mean you want to drop the row names or reset them? Why exactly do you want to do that? If you don't like row names, you could always use tibbles instead. The tidyverse doesn't like rownames either. If you expect them to always be reset they loose all their meaning.

Comment: Refer my expected output :) Actually i do not need rownames to be deleted